# Replace subsequent values in a df based on condition of first value in group

Tags: r, lag, lead

I have this type of data in an ordered R dataframe.

```
set.seed(25)

date <- sort(as.Date(sample( as.numeric(as.Date("2019-01-01")): as.numeric(as.Date("2021-03-31")), 10, 
                             replace = T), 
                     origin = '1970-01-01'))

type <- c("Football", "Football", "Rugby", "Football", "Hockey", "Tennis", "Hockey", "Basketball", "Basketball", "Rugby")

id <- c("1","1","1","1","2","2","3","4","4","5")

df <- data.frame(date,id, type)



      date id       type
  2019-04-09  1   Football
  2019-04-13  1   Football
  2019-04-20  1      Rugby
  2019-04-21  1   Football
  2019-05-31  2     Hockey
  2020-02-09  2     Tennis
  2020-03-08  3     Hockey
  2020-03-24  4 Basketball
  2020-08-18  4   Football
  2020-11-01  5      Rugby
```

The result I'm trying to get at is this:

```
    date id       type     type_2
  2019-04-09  1   Football   Football
  2019-04-13  1   Football   Football
  2019-04-20  1      Rugby      Multi
  2019-04-21  1   Football      Multi
  2019-05-31  2     Hockey     Hockey
  2020-02-09  2     Tennis      Multi
  2020-03-08  3     Hockey     Hockey
  2020-03-24  4 Basketball Basketball
  2020-08-18  4 Basketball Basketball
  2020-11-01  5      Rugby      Rugby
```

Basically, the first sport in time an id practices stays if the next sport he practices is the same as the previous one, type_2 remains the same, but as soon as he changes sport later on, he changes to multi for the rest of his values later on.

I tried do this with `lag()`, `lead()` and `if_else()` in `dplyr` but the results never come out the way I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `rleid` from `data.table` to generate the running length id for `type` variable in each `id`. Everything after the first change becomes `"Multi"`.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, type2 := replace(type, rleid(type) > 1, 'Multi'), id]
df

#          date id       type      type2
# 1: 2019-02-18  1   Football   Football
# 2: 2019-02-28  1   Football   Football
# 3: 2019-03-13  1      Rugby      Multi
# 4: 2019-09-29  1   Football      Multi
# 5: 2019-10-09  2     Hockey     Hockey
# 6: 2020-03-19  2     Tennis      Multi
# 7: 2020-04-21  3     Hockey     Hockey
# 8: 2020-06-19  4 Basketball Basketball
# 9: 2020-09-08  4 Basketball Basketball
#10: 2020-10-08  5      Rugby      Rugby
```

If you prefer to write it in `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(type2 = replace(type, rleid(type) > 1, 'Multi')) %>%
  ungroup
```